# How to resolve "JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

Tags: python, json

Can anyone suggest me what's going wrong with the following code. Tried to find solution, but none seem to work.

```
url = "https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/Housing-Development-Finance-Corp.ltd./Hdfc/500010/"
webURL = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}) #: 'Chrome/35.0.1916.47'
data = urllib.request.urlopen(webURL).read().decode('utf-8-sig') #'ISO-8859-1'
JSON_object = json.loads(data)
```

And here's the traceback:

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-207-70f91ab8d67d> in <module>
     16         #print(type(data))
     17         #encoding = webURL.info().get_content_charset('utf-8')
---> 18         JSON_object = json.loads(data)
     19 
     20         #print(req)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    346             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    347             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 348         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    349     if cls is None:
    350         cls = JSONDecoder

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    335 
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Because `data` will contain the html of that page as a string, not a JSON content. `json.loads` expects a string containing a JSON object.

Comment: If youre not sure, simply print `data` (or save it to a file) and you’ll see it isn’t pure json, hence the exception from `json.loads(data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is usually thrown when the output is actually not JSON. Which you can verify by opening the URL in your browser.